# How could I check the Form ID using hook_file_validate on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

How could I check the Form ID of the file being validated using hook_file_validate? I have to make a validation function that should only apply to a specific content type add form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it into hook_file_validate try attaching a form validation handler through hook_form_alter or hook_FORMID_form_alter. Add your validation handler with `$form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_my_form_validation_funciton'`

The for Id should be checked already so that you can just run your check on the form['#value'].